# Is storing data that rarely changes in-memory a good candidate for a singleton/cache?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, singleton

I have a class called `DataPoint` that is defined like the following. Currently, it goes through each property on an object and based on the `DataPoint`, it does some formatting like padding, trimming, etc... before it will save the record to the database.  The current implementation `makes a database call for each property` which is slow, so my first step is to get everything at once into an in-memory collection.  What else can I do below?  Is this a good candidate for a singleton since the data rarely changes and/or is it possible to cache it (if so, how)?

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Justification {get;set;}
    public int MaxLength {get;set;}
    public string Format {get;set;}


    public DataPoint GetDataPoint(string name)
    {
        var dataPoint =
            db.Query<DataPoint>("SELECT * FROM DataPoint WHERE name = @name", new {name}).FirstOrDefault();

        return dataPoint;
    }

    public T FormatObj<T>(T obj)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            var dataPoint = GetDataPoint(propertyInfo.Name);

            //Do formatting on obj Properties such as setting values, etc...
        }

        return obj;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Memory Cache. I use memory cache to cache data rarely changes or at the specific time.

Here is example:

```
public static T GetCache<T>(string key, Func<T> initializer) where T : new() {
    if (!MemoryCache.Default.Contains(key)) {
        try {
            T data = initializer();
            AddData(key, data);
            return (T)MemoryCache.Default[key];
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LogHelper.WriteError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex);
            return default(T);
        }
    }
    return (T)MemoryCache.Default[key];
}

public static void AddData(string key, object data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return;
    }
    var cacheTime = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CachingExpiredTime"]);
    AddData(key, data, cacheTime);
}

private static void AddData(string key, object data, int cacheMinute) {
    if (data == null) {
        return;
    }
    var policy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cacheMinute) };
    MemoryCache.Default.Add(new CacheItem(key, data), policy);
}
```

Comment: Would love to use this buti an stuck in .net 3.5.

Comment: @xaisoft  Don't let that stop you.  Copy from this link and implement it in .Net 3.5  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCache.cs,85751dcd91d94103

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. A singleton is rarely the answer. If you dont believe do a quick search on singleton anti pattern. The main problem being that it is hard to unit test code which uses a singleton.

A much more flexible approach is the inversion of control pattern. Basically you would would just make the class that would use your cache depend a IDataPoint instance in the constructor and then it is up the to calling point to decide how to create or reuse and which implementation of IDataPoint it wishes to provide.

Comment: The main reason why a singleton is a bad idea is [it is essentially a global variable](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/148108/22815), spreading a thin layer of lipstick on what is widely regarded as a smelly, ugly pig.